# PHP time function giving wrong time?

Tags: php, time, clock

On my website, I use the php time() function to display the time. A week ago I compared the time difference between the time returned by the time() function and the time on my computer(I use windows). The time difference was about a minute and 10 seconds but now I checked again and the time difference has grown to a minute and 50 seconds. Can anyone explain how this is possible?

Comment: You aren't clear about whether your computer is acting as the server that is executing your php time function. Is it your computer or is it a server somewhere?

Comment: Do you happen to be running this in a virtual machine?

Comment: Call your NASA dudes to synchro your space shuttle timer

Comment: I just checked and yes the time() function is returning the time on my server and that time is different from windows time. Though it is different, the difference should always remain the same, but its not?

Answer (score 0):

Set your time zone by [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

I'm not sure this would help.

Comment: Seems unlikely to be a server time zone issue.

Answer (score 0):

On some Linux dystros time is resynced via NTP on system restart only. You may install ntp daemon which will keep time delta in <10ms constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this confusing made from your computer and server.  One week you may compare with your computer time and now you check with server time.  Make sure about this.  Because server time is differ from our local computer time.

Answer (score 0):

first store time and date of message post in mysql database using predefined `function date()` for getting our local time we have to use `date_default_timezone_set()` function before date()

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$massege_post_time=date("H:i:s Y-m-d ");
```

Time And Date will store in database like `15:56:28 2018-08-09`

Where `H= 15(24 hour system) i=56(minute) s(second)=28`

```
Y(year)=2018 m(month)=08, d(day)=09
```

I answer here for previously asked question on this site [xx time ago function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461349/xx-time-ago-function-doesnt-work/51967484#51967484)